# Spacing in alignedat

Tags: align

If I compare the two equations below, the space between the brace and the first line of the cases

(-f_{0}) is different. I know that if I put \hspace{-0.1cm} before \left{ of the

second equation, I can adjust the extra space, but is there any fundamental way to remove the space

made when I start `alignedat` with `&`?

Or, you may suggest a totally different method to type the equation that I want.

```
\begin{equation*}
(G^{*} \vec{x}^{*})(\vec{w}^{*})=
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&-f_{0}^{*}(\vec{x}_{0}^{*})&&-(f_{1}^{*} \upsilon_{1}^{*})(\vec{x}_{1}^{*})-\cdots-(f_{m}^{*} \upsilon_{m}^{*})(\vec{x}_{m}^{*}) \\
&&&\text {if } \vec{u}^{*} \geq \vec{0} \text { and } \vec{x}_{0}^{*}+\cdots+\vec{x}_{m}^{*}=\vec{x}^{*}, \\
&-\infty &&\text {otherwise}.
\end{alignedat}\right.
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

```
\begin{equation*}
(G^{*} \vec{x}^{*})(\vec{w}^{*})=
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{3}
-f_{0}^{*}(\vec{x}_{0}^{*})&&-(f_{1}^{*} \upsilon_{1}^{*})(\vec{x}_{1}^{*})-\cdots-(f_{m}^{*} \upsilon_{m}^{*})(\vec{x}_{m}^{*}) \\
&&\text {if } \vec{u}^{*} \geq \vec{0} \text { and } \vec{x}_{0}^{*}+\cdots+\vec{x}_{m}^{*}=\vec{x}^{*}, \\
-\infty &&\text {otherwise}.
\end{alignedat}\right.
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to choose the alignment point anyway, I propose a different approach, where you state the desired width of the object (default 3em):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\newcommand{\splitcase}[2][3em]{%
  \makebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle#2$} &
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \addtolength{\dimen0}{-1em}%
  \hspace*{\dimen0}%
  \\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
(G^{*} \vec{x}^{*})(\vec{w}^{*})=
\begin{cases}
\splitcase{
  -f_{0}^{*}(\vec{x}_{0}^{*})
  -(f_{1}^{*} \upsilon_{1}^{*})(\vec{x}_{1}^{*})
  -\dots
  -(f_{m}^{*} \upsilon_{m}^{*})(\vec{x}_{m}^{*})
}
  &\text{if $\vec{u}^{*} \geq \vec{0}$ and
         $\vec{x}_{0}^{*}+\dots+\vec{x}_{m}^{*}=\vec{x}^{*}$},
\\
-\infty &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
(G^{*} \vec{x}^{*})(\vec{w}^{*})=
\begin{cases}
\splitcase[5em]{
  -f_{0}^{*}(\vec{x}_{0}^{*})
  -(f_{1}^{*} \upsilon_{1}^{*})(\vec{x}_{1}^{*})
  -\dots
  -(f_{m}^{*} \upsilon_{m}^{*})(\vec{x}_{m}^{*})
}
  &\text{if $\vec{u}^{*} \geq \vec{0}$ and
         $\vec{x}_{0}^{*}+\dots+\vec{x}_{m}^{*}=\vec{x}^{*}$},
\\
-\infty &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't change much about the setup of the first equation except (a) make sure the `-` symbol at the start of the math rows is typeset as a unary symbol, (b) change `\begin{alignedat}{3}` to `\begin{alignedat}{2}`, and (c) leave a bit more whitespace between rows 2 and 3. Whether to use arrow accents or bold-facing a vector is largely a matter of taste; if you use the arrow method, be sure to leave a bit of space before the superscript `*` symbols.

The spacing around the curly brace is unchanged if one uses `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` instead of `\left\{ ... \right.`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignedat' env and '\text' macro
\usepackage{bm} % for '\bm' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
(G^{*} \vec{x}^{\mkern1.5mu*})(\vec{w}^{\mkern1.5mu*})
&= \left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&{-}f_{0}^{*}(\vec{x}_{0}^{\mkern1.5mu*})
  &&-(f_{1}^{*} \upsilon_{1}^{*})(\vec{x}_{1}^{\mkern1.5mu*})
    -\dots-(f_{m}^{*} \upsilon_{m}^{*})(\vec{x}_{m}^{\mkern1.5mu*}) \\
  &&&\text{if $\vec{u}^{\mkern1.5mu*} \geq \vec{0}$ and 
              $\vec{x}_{0}^{\mkern1.5mu*}+\dots+\vec{x}_{m}^{\mkern1.5mu*}
                =\vec{x}^{\mkern1.5mu*}$}, \\[1ex]
&{-}\infty 
  &&\text{otherwise}.
\end{alignedat}
\right. \\ % end of first equation
(G^{*} \bm{x}^{*})(\bm{w}^{*})
&= \left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&{-}f_{0}^{*}(\bm{x}_{0}^{*})
  &&-(f_{1}^{*} \upsilon_{1}^{*})(\bm{x}_{1}^{*})
    -\dots-(f_{m}^{*} \upsilon_{m}^{*})(\bm{x}_{m}^{*}) \\
  &&&\text{if $\bm{u}^{*} \geq \bm{0}$ and 
              $\bm{x}_{0}^{*}+\dots+\bm{x}_{m}^{*}
                =\bm{x}^{*}$}, \\[1ex]
&{-}\infty 
  &&\text{otherwise}.
\end{alignedat}
\right. % end of second equation
(G^{*} \bm{x}^{*})(\bm{w}^{*})
&= \begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&{-}f_{0}^{*}(\bm{x}_{0}^{*})
  &&-(f_{1}^{*} \upsilon_{1}^{*})(\bm{x}_{1}^{*})
    -\dots-(f_{m}^{*} \upsilon_{m}^{*})(\bm{x}_{m}^{*}) \\
  &&&\text{if $\bm{u}^{*} \geq \bm{0}$ and 
              $\bm{x}_{0}^{*}+\dots+\bm{x}_{m}^{*}
                =\bm{x}^{*}$}, \\[1ex]
&{-}\infty 
  &&\text{otherwise}.
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, I still find that \left\{\begin{alignedat} ... has more space than \begin{cases} between the brace and the equation. Is this a normal thing? or is there any way to improve futther?

Comment: @daesungkim - Did you maybe miss my suggestion to "(a) make sure the `-` symbol at the start of the math row is typeset as a unary symbol"? I've updated my answer to demonstrate that the spacing around the curly brace is the same whether one uses `\left\{ ... \right.` or `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}`.

Comment: What I meant was if I used the case environment like below, although it does not exactly give what I want.

(G^{*} \bm{x}^{*})(\bm{w}^{*})&=
\begin{cases}
-f_{0}^{*}(\bm{x}_{0}^{*})-&(f_{1}^{*} \upsilon_{1}^{*})(\bm{x}_{1}^{*})-\cdots-(f_{m}^{*} \upsilon_{m}^{*})(\bm{x}_{m}^{*}) \\
&\text {if } \bm{u}^{*} \geq \bm{0} \text { and } \bm{x}_{0}^{*}+\cdots+\bm{x}_{m}^{*}=\bm{x}^{*}, \\
-\infty &\text {otherwise}.
\end{cases}

Comment: @daesungkim - Sorry, but using the `cases` environment in the way suggested in your comment is not appropriate. You had it right earlier, when you encased the material to the right of the curly brace in an `alignedat` environment. If you insist on *not* using an `alignedat` environment, you need to take the route suggested in [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569879/5001).

Comment: OK. I understand. Thanks for your solution using ```{-}```. It was simple but very helpful!